# How to override default linker compiling with configure?

Tags: macos, gcc, linker, installation

I need to install a package ([ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/root-version-v5-32-00-patch-release-notes)) from source on **OSX** using **GCC** 4.7.3 as a compiler. Default compiler on OSX is clang, so I look to `configure` command options to change it. I see that I can change it:

```
 with compiler options, prefix with --with-, overrides default value

  cc                 alternative C compiler and options to be used
  cxx                alternative C++ compiler and options to be used
```

But when I run:

```
./configure --with-cxx=g++ --with-cc=gcc
```

I see:

```
Checking for C compiler ... gcc
Checking for C++ compiler ... g++
Checking for linker (LD) ... clang++
```

So it trying to compile with gcc and link with clang, this obviously leads to failure. But I can't find an option in `configure` how to change linker used by `make`.

Is there a default options of `configure` to change linker? Something like `--with-cxxlinker`.
If not - how can I find and change the linker used by specific package?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to run an older build on OS X 10.9?

Comment: @l'L'l, older build of ROOT? Any build is ok for me. I had the same issuers with 5.34.

Comment: I've built this many times, and never had an issue, although maybe there's a reason you want to use gcc instead of clang I presume. Anyway, this one is specific to gcc, so it should work: ftp://root.cern.ch/root/root_v5.34.14.macosx106-x86_64-gcc-4.2.tar.gz

Comment: @l'L'l, thank you, but this is binary. How exactly did you built it many times? Did you do it on OSX 10.9?

Comment: Instead of giving you conflicting information I'll send you to a topic that might give you a better insight on similar problems: http://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17190

Comment: @l'L'l, thanks, I don't see much connection with my problem. I better try to use the binary you gave above. It seems to be working with my packages.

Comment: If you need to compile with gcc on 10.9 it's often not going to be as simple as changing a flag within ./configure unfortunately. Apple didn't make it easy on those of us who might have needed to continue using something for whatever reason when they took it out. I was able to install tools that Apple removed from 10.9, but I'm not completely confident that by putting them back is the best idea. I have older versions of OS X installed on other partitions for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of building `ROOT` from source is to use git and obtain the most recent [production version](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/category/package-context/production-version) available. As of today that is version [5.34.19](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/production-version-534).

Open Terminal.app (then use each of the commands in succession):

```
cd ~/desktop && mkdir root
git clone http://root.cern.ch/git/root.git && cd root
./configure
make
make install
```

The nice thing about using git is that it contains a complete source tree for all systems (72 MB). You shouldn't need to use any special `./configure` commands (unless you want to use add-on components).

You could also install the Mac Ports version by using the command:

```
sudo port install root
```

Comment: May be I was unclear, but I need gcc version on OSX. The proposed commands will build with default compiler, which is clang, so I will not be able to link root to other gcc-compiled packages.

Comment: The Mac Ports version should be gcc, info here: http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/build-prerequisites